# Draft JS recognize img from HTML

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs

I'm using Facebook's `draft-js` to create a WYSIWYG. I'm trying to convert HTML to editorState using the native `convertFromHtml`. But it's not recognizing the `img` tag.

```
import draftJs from 'draft-js'
const blocksFromHTML = convertFromHTML("<img src='some/img.png' />", draftJs.getSafeBodyFromHTML, draftJs.DefaultDraftBlockRenderMap);
const contentState = draftJs.ContentState.createFromBlockArray(blocksFromHTML);
editorState = draftJs.EditorState.createWithContent(contentState);
```

Doing so completely removes the image. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

[Example of using convertFromHTML in draft-js 0.10.0](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/blob/0.10-stable/examples/draft-0-10-0/convertFromHTML/convert.html#L56) should work (the code was a bit simplified by me):

```
      const sampleMarkup = '<img src="image.png" />';

      const blocksFromHTML = convertFromHTML(sampleMarkup);
      const state = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(
        blocksFromHTML.contentBlocks,
        blocksFromHTML.entityMap,
      );

      this.state = {
        editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(state),
      };
```

Answer (score 1):

the Mikhail Khazov solution is partially correct, I had to add the img tag into the figure tag, that should solve the problem